# How can I fix the error "boot! And select proper boot device"?

Tags: boot, motherboard, computer-building, computer-architecture

I tried to fix that. Pressed ctrl+alt+Del and it shows the motherboard settings. I don't know what should I do?

Comment: You need to select a primary boot device, check your motherboard manual for guidance on how to navigate around the BIOS.

Comment: I can't, I don't have them and I don't know the model...

Comment: What is the computer? Did it work before and what have changed? Try to press F2 when booting to enter into the BIOS and let us know the available boot devices. If the hard disk is not listed, let us know what you have as disks in the BIOS. Screenshots will be best.

Comment: [link](https://images.anandtech.com/doci/12542/how_to_overclock_using_gigabyte_am4_motherboard_%285%29.jpg)

Comment: it shows me like the picture i uploded